# fb realtime updates

Tags: facebook

```
$param = array(
  'access_token' => $this->getAccessToken(),
  'object' => 'user',
  'fields' => 'first_name,last_name,birthday,email,friends,locale,location,relationship_status',
  'callback_url' => 'http://x.com/post',
  'verify_token' => VTOKEN
);

$subs = data('fb')->getFb()->api('/y/subscriptions', 'POST', $param);
```

When I try to subcribe with that code above, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught OAuthException: (#2201) response does not match challenge, expected value =
```

I am 100% sure that the callback url is available and the code on the callback url is:

```
if (
   $method == 'GET' && $_GET['hub_mode'] == 'subscribe' &&       
   $_GET['hub_verify_token'] == VTOKEN) {
        echo $_GET['hub_challenge'];
} else if ($method == 'POST') { 
        // code me
}
```

So it should work, what could be the problem?

Comment: How do you determine $method?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the callback is available? Did you try a GET call on your own?

Also, take a look on the following:
https://github.com/facebook/real-time/blob/master/samples/php/callback.php